# parse localDateTime string correctly into spring boot @pathVariable

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I'm trying to get all data of a user of a user with a timestamp:

```
@GetMapping("/datum/{userID}/{timeStamp}")
    List<Datum> getDataSingleUserTimeRange(@PathVariable Long userID, @PathVariable LocalDateTime timeStamp)
    {
          ....
    }
```

Now to test this Spring Boot rest api, in postman, I made this call `GET` and url - *`http://localhost:8080/datum/2/2019-12-15T19:37:15.330995`*.

But it gives me error saying : **Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.time.LocalDateTime'**

How can I resolve this ??

Comment: `:` is a special character in URI . I would use a timestamp here not a formated datetime

Comment: Your variable is named `time`. But the path variable is named `timeStamp`.

Comment: @JBNizet correct, but after correcting that, I get this error - 'Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.time.LocalDateTime'

Comment: That's another issue. https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/format/annotation/DateTimeFormat.html

Comment: @JBNizet please see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59344878/spring-jpa-query-is-returning-404-no-message)

Comment: @Jens please see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59344878/spring-jpa-query-is-returning-404-no-message)

Comment: @MaifeeUlAsad Can't get you

Comment: I added a new question, can you see that please, I would be nice if you have any solutions or suggestions

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2017/08/parsing-of-localdate-query-parameters-in-spring-boot/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if it is the most modest way to do this or not, but here is what I have done :

```
@GetMapping("/datum/{userID}/{timeStamp}")
    List<Datum> getDataSingleUserTimeRange(@PathVariable Long userID, @PathVariable String timeStamp)
    {
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE_TIME;
        LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(timeStamp, formatter);
        ...
        return datumRepository.findUsingTime(start,end);
    }
```

Passed as string and parsed that. And`dateTime.truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.NECESARRY_UNIT);` can be used as well.

Comment: I tried but that gives me can't convert string to localDateTime..

Answer (score 2):

You need [@DateTimeFormat](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/format/annotation/DateTimeFormat.html#pattern--) with custom pattern that matches to your input

```
@GetMapping("/datum/{userID}/{timeStamp}")
List<Datum> getDataSingleUserTimeRange(@PathVariable Long userID, @PathVariable @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS") LocalDateTime timeStamp)
{

}
```

Comment: It gives can't convert String to LocalDateTime, type mismatch error...

Comment: i tested it on spring boot 2.x which is working for me @MaifeeUlAsad

Comment: i will do it again as soon as i turn my desktop on and send you the actual log..

Comment: please see [this snap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tU70q.png), this is what i get when i use this approach

Comment: because the input date you are passing has only 2 digit of milliseconds, so use formatter according to that like this `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SS` @MaifeeUlAsad

Comment: take look [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J6zGX.png) and [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QfimP.png), it would be very nice if i could use dateTimeFormat, but it doesn't work with me for some reason, spring version - 2.2.1 rel and java - 1.8 with maven dep..